# The STATICFILES_DIRS setting is not a tuple or list. Eventhough it did not contain a comma

Tags: python, static

HI I am new to **static files** but I got this error called `STATICFILES_DIRS setting is not a tuple or list`. Which I do not understand as *it is does not contain any commas*. I hope someone can help me. Yes, I have imported os.
Traceback:

```
ERRORS:
?: (staticfiles.E001) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting is not a tuple or list.
        HINT: Perhaps you forgot a trailing comma?
```

settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '')
    )
```

Comment: `STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ''))` must be `STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ''),)` **with a trailing comma**. By the way, the latter `STATICFILES_DIRS` overrides your previous one, I don't think that's on purpose?

Comment: It was on purpose. It was for my clarity. @fsimonjetz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @fsimonjetz for helping me answer this question I changed this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '')
```

)

to

```
 STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ''),)
```

Comment: Exactly.  It's not the parentheses that turn it into a tuple, it's the comma.

Answer (score 0):

For people who didn't understand why this error still shown even the location of directory is exist and clear.

Django asks for the `STATICFILES_DIRS` to be on tuple or list structure because is expecting many directories as value, so it's not efficient to assign only `string` to `STATICFILES_DIRS`

So we need to put this direcory on `[]` or `()`.